# WordPress: Redirecting a drafted post

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to set up a redirect for **drafted** posts of the post type "Personnel", as we'd rather show a page with a custom message than a 404 page in this instance. I have added the following to `functions.php` (adopted from [this older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256751/redirect-if-a-post-is-in-draft-status)) which for some reason only works for logged-in users- otherwise, the general 404 page shows. I've also tried adding the redirect to the `single-personnel.php` template, but it has no effect. I'm wondering how to get this redirect working for all users (logged in or not) and/or if there's a better way to implement the redirect? Thanks for any insight here.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'inactive_personnel_redirect', 0 );
function inactive_personnel_redirect() {
    global $post;
    if( ( $post->post_status == 'draft' ) && ( is_singular('personnel') ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() . '/about-us/inactive', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see why this hook should behave differently for logged-in vs non logged-in users. Do you have any caching plugins in use?

Comment: @CBroe I don't have any caching plugins and have tried using multiple browsers and still the same result- it doesn't seem to make much sense. I've also tried using different hooks to attach the redirect, but doesn't help.